# Magento product from a category not showing when changes in xml file

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I have a strange problem in Magento. I wanted to add a slider in my header where all the products from one category will show in the slider. For that I just created `fetured.phtml`file and inside that I made my code like this

```
<?php $cat_id = 35; ?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);?>
<?php $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');?>
<?php Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);?>
<?php  $i=0; foreach ($collection as $_product):?>
<?php if($i++%7==0): ?>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
  <?php endif ?>
  <div class="da-slide">
    <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></h2>
    <p class="price"><?php echo $formattedSpecialPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false);?></p>
    <p><?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?> </p> <br />

    <a class="da-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">Shop Now</a>

    <div class="da-img"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(90, 90); ?>" width="120" height="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></div>

    <!--.da-img-->

   </div><!--.da-slide-->
   <?php endforeach ?>
    <nav class="da-arrows">
      <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
      <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
    </nav><!--.da-arrows-->
  </div><!--#da-slider-->
 </div><!--.container-->
```

After that as I wanted to show the products in the header I went to the `catalog.xml` file `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/catalog.xml` and in that I made like this

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
  <label>Page Header</label>
    <block type="catalog/product_featured" name="catalog.product.featured" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml" />
      <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
    </block>
 </block>
```

Here I have done like this to show the fetured product category in the header of a slider. But it is not showing the products. But if I change my codes to

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
      <label>Page Header</label>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product.featured" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml" />
          <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
        </block>
```

it is showing the product in the slider. Can someone kindly tell me what's the issue here? Any help and suggesions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the first code not showing the products is that you are using `catalog/product_featured` as your block type.
Magento tries to get the block file from Block folder but it fails because there is no `Featured.php` in Block folder.
When you use `catalog/product_list` as block type then it finds the `List.php` from block folder and displays the results.
If you want your first code to work, just create a file in Block folder named `Featured.php`
Hope this helps..